# How to find $x$ such that $\tan5x=\tan x$ and $\sin5x=\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

My math teacher told my class to solve for $x$ in:
$$1)\tan5x=\tan x$$$$2)\sin5x=\sin x$$I couldn't understand. It says to write $\tan5x$ in terms of $\tan x$ and same for $\sin5x$ to $\sin x$. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand?

You want to find some $x$ where the above is true.

Comment: Do you not understand because you don't know how to write tan 5x in terms of tan x? Look through your notes you might have learned some formulas that help you simplify tan 5x. For example, tan 5x = tan (x+4x)

Answer (score 3):

This answer does not do things in the style mentioned by your math teacher. But it is simple, so may be of interest.

Note that $\tan a=\tan b$ precisely if $a$ and $b$ differ by an integer multiple of $\pi$. In particular, for $\tan 5x=\tan x$ we want $4x$ to be a multiple of $\pi$.

The analysis for $\sin 5x=\sin x$ is similar, a little more complicated because in addition to $\sin(a+2\pi)=\sin a$ we have $\sin(\pi-a)=\sin a$.

Comment: $$\sin5x=\sin x\iff 5x=x\; (\iff x=0)\;,\;\;or\;\;5x=\pi-x\iff x=\frac\pi6+2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$$ Why is the above more complicated?

Comment: Two cases instead of one.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, yes. Thank you.

Comment: @Timbuc That's almost right, but incomplete

Answer (score 3):

By the compounded angle formula, for instance,

$$ \sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y) $$

one can reduce the size of the angle of a trigonometric function. If the angle is an odd multiple of $x$, then it can be reduced to a polynomial of the trigonometric function of $x$ of the same kind.

For example,

$$ \sin(3x) = \sin(2x+x) = \sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)\sin(x) $$

Meanwhile,

$$ \sin(2x)\cos(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos^2(x) = 2\sin(x)(1 - \sin^2(x)) = 2\sin(x) - 2\sin^3(x)$$
$$ \cos(2x)\sin(x) = (1 - 2\sin^2(x))\sin(x) = \sin(x) - 2\sin^3(x) $$

Therefore,

$$ \sin(3x) = (2\sin(x) - 2\sin^3(x)) + (\sin(x) - 2\sin^3(x)) = 3\sin(x) - 4\sin^3(x) $$

Now $\sin(5x)$ can also be written into a polynomial of $\sin(x)$ in a similar manner. Same for $\tan(5x)$.

Comment: Thanks @ziyuang for helping me to edit. I am relatively new to Latex and always forget some basic things. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @CheungSW, What if $$\sin(7.5x)=\sin(\pi x)?$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, since these functions have a period of $2\pi$, although being completely different functions, but they do intersect at all integer values of x,
$$
\sin(\frac{x\pi}{2}) = \sin(\frac{5x\pi}{2})
$$

The same goes for tangent function, except the period being of only $\pi$ therefore

$$
\tan(\frac{x\pi}{4}) = \tan(\frac{5x\pi}{4})
$$

Over all integer values of x except for those such that make the function undefined such as $\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{4\pi}{2},....,\frac{2(1+n)\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Timbuc Yes my error, I have fixed it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation
$$ \tan 5x = \tan x \Rightarrow 5x = x + n\pi \Rightarrow 4x = n\pi \Rightarrow x = \frac{n\pi}{4} $$

The second equation has 2 cases, because $\sin x = \sin (\pi - x)$, so $\sin 5x = \sin x$ means

$$ 5x = x + 2n\pi \Rightarrow 4x = 2n\pi \Rightarrow x = \frac{n\pi}{2} $$
or
$$ 5x = \pi - x + 2n\pi \Rightarrow 6x = (2n+1)\pi \Rightarrow x = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{6} $$